# kula devi/devata of Shree Rama?

Tags: ramayana, rama, devi

Is there any mention of Kula Devi or Devata name of Shree Rama in Srimad Valmiki Ramayana?

Answer (score 2):

It's Lord Vishnu/Narayana. Rama worshipped Narayana before his coronation ceremonies in Ayodhya Khanda -

> After Vasistha left, Rama took bath and meditated on Lord Narayana
> with undistracted mind along with his wide-eyed wife, Seetha. Taking
> the vessel with clarified butter on his head as per scriptures, he
> offered to Lord Vishnu the clarified butter, by dropping it into the
> blazing fire. Rama ate the remainder of clarified butter after
> finishing the sacrifice, which he performed for his own good, silently
> meditated on Lord Narayana with controlled mind and slept along with
> Seetha on a properly laid bed of Kusa grass in a splendid temple of
> Lord Vishnu.

Ayodhya Kanda, sarga 6

Kaushalya was also worshipping lord Vishnu -

> At that time, Kausalya having spent the whole night with
> steadfastness, who performing worship to Vishnu, at dawn, for the
> welfare of her son.

Ayodhya Kanda, sarga 20

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the other answer already given, it is also mentioned that Devi Kausalya, worshipped Lord Vishnu for the welfare of her son Sri Rama.

**Ayodhya Kanda, sarga 17** (critical edition)

> kausalyApi tadA devI rAtriM sthitvA samAhitA |
> prabhAte tv akarot pUjAM viSNoH putrahitaiSiNI || 6

> Queen Kousalya had spent the night in a self-controlled way. In the morning, for the welfare of her son, she was worshipping Vishnu.

It can be assumed that Lord Vishnu is the kula devata.

Answer (score 2):

Bhagwaan Jagganatha ji, who is Shri Hari Vishnu ji himself, is the kula devata of Raghu vansha clan.

This is further strengthened on the fact that we have various references to Siya-Ramji and their mother kaushalya devi worshipping Narayan or Vishnu Bhagawaan, as we can see from other answers on this question too. [Gita Press Ramayan](https://ibb.co/cLMR1wb) interprets Jagganatha word as Vishnu ji. We can read it through this link too - https://archive.org/details/fdag_shrimad-valmiki-ramayan-with-hindi-trans.-part-2-series-no.-76-gita-press/page/n851/mode/2up?view=theater

Bhagawaan Shri Ram ji himself answers this in the Ramayan by Maharishi Valmiki in Book 7 called Uttara Kanda.

> https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424883.html
>
> Chapter 108
>
> बिभीषणमथोवाच राक्षसेन्द्रं महायशाः । यावत्प्रजा धरिष्यन्ति तावत्त्वं
> वै बिभीषण । राक्षसेन्द्र महावीर्य लङ्कास्थस्त्वं धरिष्यसि ।। ७.१०८.२७
> ।।
>
> यावच्चन्द्रश्च सूर्यश्च यावत्तिष्ठति मेदिनी । यावच्च मत्कथा लोके
> तावद्राज्यं तवास्त्विह ।। ७.१०८.२८ ।।
>
> शासितस्त्वं सखित्वेन कार्यं ते मम शासनम् । प्रजाः संरक्ष धर्मेण
> नोत्तरं वक्तुमर्हसि ।। ७.१०८.२९ ।।
>
> किञ्चान्यद्वक्तुमिच्छामि राक्षसेन्द्र महामते ।। ७.१०८.३० ।।
>
> आराधय **जगन्नाथमिक्ष्वाकुकुलदैवतम्** । आराधनीयमनिशं सर्वैर्दैवैः सवासवैः
> ।। ७.१०८.३१ ।। तथेति प्रतिजग्राह रामवाक्यं विभीषणः । राजा
> राक्षसमुख्यानां राघवाज्ञामनुस्मरन् ।। ७.१०८.३२ ।।
>
> Thereafter he said to Bibishana, the King of the Rakshasas:—
>
> “As long as people exist, O Mighty Lord of the Rakshasas, do you
> remain in Lanka. As long as the moon and sun continue to shine on the
> earth, as long as they speak of me in the world, so long shall thine
> empire endure; this is the will of your friend, do you obey! Govern
> your people according to justice and do not question this further. One
> thing more I wish to say to you, **O Mighty Monarch of the Rakshasas, do
> you worship the Divinity of the House of Ikshvaku, the Guide of the
> Universe, Shri Jagannath,** whom the Devas themselves with their leaders
> perpetually adore.”
>
> “So shall it be,” answered Bibishana,

Ikshvaku being the first king of Shri Ram ji's dynasty, and hence it is called Ikshvaku-vansha.

And thus as told by Bhagawaan Ram ji, the kula devta of their clan is a specific form of Vishnu - Lord Jagannath (which is Vishnu himself, if I'm not misplaced).

*I have earlier concluded that the word Jagganatha as Puri exclusively, and I understand that it might be inconclusive for some of us. But my conclusion were based on what my guruji lectures, he gave cyclic nature of time and other reasons like Brahma ji praising Ram ji as Krishna (an avatara which is yet to come) after the Lanka war.*

**Anyway, the major question was who is the kula devata of Ramji and the answer is it is Bhagawaan Jagganatha ji, who is Shri Hari Vishnu Bhagwaan ji himself.** Even if we do not specifically conclude the Jagganatha word as the god of Puri temple, it is Vishnu ji only (as further supported by Gita press hindi Ramayan translation).

Comment: I was thinking it's one of the form of Devi herself. But looks like it's not the case as per Srimad Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: How Jagannatha can *only* mean Puri Jagannath temple? Balabhardra, Subhadra, Jagannatha forms (wooden murtis) came after Krishna Avatara. It was/is called Purushottama Kshetra and Neela Madhava as per Purushottama Kshetra Mahatmya of Skanda Purana.. can we consider this as *your speculation*? share any source which explicitly states Puri jagannatha swami is kuladevata of Sri Rama..

Comment: @TheDestroyer Ah! You're right. How did I miss the point.

Comment: moderator @thedestroyer why would you assume that Jagganatha cannot only mean Puri Vishnu? u r knowledgeable already as per your site footprint. Time is cyclic, why can't it be puri I ask u? [tarakasur](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43057/how-did-tarakasura-know-about-future-incarnations-of-lord-vishnu) seems to know beforehand about avatarams beforehand. Brahma ji refer Shri Rama as krishna after war. Why similar argument not extend here? (1/3)

Comment: for whatever reason you down vote, rather than having a discussion is beyond me, as a moderator you ought to have better patience, considering i'm new user. But over a few months here I can see why this platform can't have any productive and uplifting discussions and users are arm twisted into fleeing off this platform. (2/3)

Comment: @thelittlenaruto even if we are to discount that Jagganatha is not the puri God. It doesn't change the fact that Jagganatha is a reference to Vishnu ji only, I clearly stated that as my final line in the original answer, which was conveniently ignored by downvotes. Regarding me concluding it Puri I have edited it now, my conclusion was based on what my guruji told us in one of his pravachanas, but I understand that that is not a valid source on this site and rightly so.(3/3)

Comment: Anyways i hope my answer answers what was asked in the question. Rest all is discussion stuff.

Comment: @Draupadi because wooden Murtis came later which all shastras say. although Krishna avatara could have happened many times.. Term Jagannath is very generic. Ishwara is used for Shiva and Bhagavan for Vishnu usually but it doesn't mean they only represent always Shiva and Vishnu.  Anyways, i expect source for that statement where jagannatha shows Puri Jagannath form of Vishnu, which is right now Balabhadra, Subhadra sametha Jagannatha Swami.. Also, downvotes are here to show disagreement, not something else.

Comment: @Draupadi "But over a few months here I can see why this platform can't have any productive and uplifting discussions and users are arm twisted into fleeing off this platform." very surprising to find this allegation from new user. Can you give more information on this? There could be many reasons why some users can become inactive or delete old accounts and come with new accounts. Just because someone leaves, it doesn't mean they were made to leave forcefully.